# Simulate Principal Policy using assumed role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I was wondering how to use `simulate-principal-policy` using the AWS CLI for an assumed role.

To provide some context, as part of my application's startup, I want to ensure that the application has the necessary permissions to access all the AWS resources it needs. I do this by getting the caller identity using `aws sts get-caller-identity` and use the returned caller identity as the policy source arn for the `simulate-principal-policy` request.

When our application runs on EC2, it uses an assumed role. so, `get-caller-identity` returns an assumed role arn.

If I try to execute `simulate-principal-policy` using my user arn as the policy source arn, the command works fine.

```
aws iam simulate-principal-policy --action-names "sqs:Receivemessage" --policy-source-arn "arn:aws:sts::123456789021:user/divesh"
```

However, trying to execute the command above by using an assumed role reports an error.

```
aws iam simulate-principal-policy --action-names "sqs:Receivemessage" --policy-source-arn "arn:aws:sts::123456789021:assumed-role/development/development-session"
An error occurred (InvalidInput) when calling the SimulatePrincipalPolicy operation: Invalid Entity Arn: arn:aws:sts::123456789021:assumed-role/development/development-session does not clearly define entity type and name.
```

Our application runs on a Kubernetes cluster and uses [kiam](https://github.com/uswitch/kiam) to associate IAM roles to pods.

Comment: In your example, you have the --policy-source-arn` set to the arn of an assumed role.  (`...456789021:assumed-role/dev...`) Have you tried using a role's arn?

Comment: That is exactly what the problem is. When my application runs on EC2, `get-caller-identity` returns an assumed role arn.

Comment: Even when I use the actual role's arn in a command, I get an `implicitDeny` with a `"MissingContextValues": ["aws:username"]`

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that our application runs inside a Kubernetes cluster and uses kiam for associating IAM roles to pods.

Comment: Works great for me.  `$ aws --profile xxxx iam simulate-principal-policy --policy-source-arn arn:aws:iam::1234567890987:role/admin --action-names "sqs:ReceiveMessage"`

Comment: the Missing Context Values might have more to do with the action you're specifying and the permission that grants it, than the `siulate-principal-policy` itself.  Like I said, I was a ble to call taht with a role arn and get the expected results ( in my case, allowed as part of an admin access policy )

Comment: Ah yes, I had not included the resource arns in my request :-) Thanks for that

Comment: But the original question still holds, I still can't use an assumed role in the call to `simulate-principal-policy`

Comment: An assumed role session name isn't necessarily unique to one session, and I *suspect* that is at the root of the *"does not clearly..."* error.  It isn't clear whether this is possible.  (It's also not really clear that it provides any meaningful value other than a false sense of assurance.)

Comment: I also hit a similar issue.  Did you eventually solve it?

Comment: I eventually moved on from the company where I was working on this problem, but while I was there, we decided to use an alternate approach for checking policies that did not involve using `simulate-principal-policy`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your request is that you are using the "Profile ARN" instead of the "Role ARN". To get the Role Arn, you can do the following:

1. Pull the Role Name from the `Instance Profile Arn`:

`arn:aws:sts::123456789021:assumed-role/development/development-session` becomes `development/development-session`

2. Get the instance profile based on that name:

`aws iam get-instance-profile --instance-profile-name Instance Profile Arn`

3. Find the Role Arn in the resulting document:

```json
{
   "InstanceProfile":{
      "Roles":[
         {
            "Arn":"arn:aws:iam::992863558783:role/YourRole"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

4. Use this ARN in simulate-principal-policy

`aws iam simulate-principal-policy --action-names "sqs:Receivemessage" --policy-source-arn "arn:aws:iam::992863558783:role/YourRole"`

In Python, the script would look like this:

```py
import boto3

iam= boto3.client('iam')

profileArn = 'arn:aws:sts::123456789021:assumed-role/development/development-session'
iamProfileName = iamInstanceProfileArn.split(':assumed-role/')[1]
profile = iam.get_instance_profile(InstanceProfileName=iamProfileName)
policySourceArns = []

for role in profile['InstanceProfile']['Roles']:
    policySourceArns.append(role['Arn'])

retval = iam.simulate_principal_policy(
    PolicySourceArn = policySourceArns[0],
    ActionNames = ['sqs:Receivemessage']
)
```